# Quantum Chemistry Help FWHM

Tags: homework-and-exercises, probability, statistics

I am struggling with this question and cannot find any resources to help me. Even the tutors at my school don't know how to help me and my professor just tells me to reference the slides, but I have been staring at the question for days and I have no idea how to answer it. I think I normalized it okay, I got e to come out to 1 and made the normalization come to zero, but I am unsure if that is correct.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Wouls [statistics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Have you tried looking up what [FWHM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_width_at_half_maximum) means?

Comment: *I got e to come out to 1.* $e$ [isn’t a variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) so it can’t be 1.

Comment: This question is about the mathematics of probability and not about physics.

Comment: *made the normalization come to zero, but I am unsure if that is correct* It isn’t. What do you understand normalization to mean?

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus *I've got no idea what an FWHM is.* It’s the “full-width-at-half-maximum”, as the question said. BTW, your integral is incorrect.

Comment: @Lorena Alvarado I left off the minus sign in the exponential earlier, you want $\int Ae^{-x^2/\alpha^2}\;dx=1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $P(x)$ is a probability distribution then integrating over the whole line:

$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(x)\,dx = 1.
$

For the [Gaussian distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#:%7E:text=In%20statistics%2C%20a%20normal%20distribution,Probability%20density%20function), this normalization factor comes from the integral of $e^{-x^2}$ over the whole space, which is $\sqrt{\pi}$, hence the denominator, $a\,\sqrt{2\pi}$, ensures the distribution is normalized. The now normalized probability distribution becomes:

$P(x) = \frac{1}{a\,\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/(2a^{2})}$.

The Full Width at Half Maximum (FWHM) for a Gaussian distribution is found by determining the width of the curve at the point where the function's value is half of its maximum value. The maximum value of a normalized Gaussian occurs at $x=0$, which is $P(0) = \frac{1}{a\,\sqrt{2\pi}}$. Setting $P(x) = \frac{1}{2}P(0)$ and solving for $x$, we get:

$
\frac{e^{-x^2/(2a^2)}}{a\sqrt{2\pi}} = \frac{1}{2a\sqrt{2\pi}}.
$

Solving this equation for $x$ gives us the relationship between FWHM and $\sigma$, yielding:

FWHM $ = 2a\sqrt{2\ln(2)}$.

The FWHM of a Gaussian distribution is directly proportional to the standard deviation $\sigma = a$, with the constant of proportionality being $2\sqrt{2\ln(2)} \approx 2.35482$. This means that the FWHM is about 2.35 times larger than the standard deviation for a Gaussian distribution.

Comment: Good job on this! Just wondering, how did you arrive at the conclusion $\sigma=a$?

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus, thanks! The definition of the normal distribution implies that $\sigma = a$, but you can also prove this to yourself by performing the integral of $x^{2}$ times the distribution over the normalization factor. That's actually $\sigma^{2}$. the square root of that is $\sigma$